# Connection for 6 raspberry pi camera modules?

Tags: camera, modules

Any ideas, I want to configure 6 cameras for 360 degree view

Comment: you have not stated what your problem is. Do you have 6 raspberry Pis and 6 camera modules or are you trying to do this with less than one Pi per module?

Answer (score 3):

You probably want a seventh, central Pi controlling 6 other Pis, all connected to the same network.

The master Pi will send a command to the 6 other Pis to take the photograph. The 6 other 'slave' Pis will each have a camera module. Remember you can't have more than one camera module per Pi.

Take a look at this - might give you some ideas
http://makezine.com/2014/02/28/building-a-bullet-time-rig-at-the-raspberry-pi-jamboree/

Comment: Couldn't one Pi control all the other Pis? Only six would be needed then...

Comment: Probably. Im not sure how much processing power is needed to actually fire the camera so was hedging my bets

Answer (score 1):

You'll likely need to have atleast six Pis for six camera modules, as each Pi only has one CSI port (next to the ethernet connector). The other similar port on the Pi is a DSI port for a LCD display - from [here](http://elinux.org/RPi_Low-level_peripherals#MIPI_CSI-2):

> ## MIPI CSI-2
>
> On the production board<sub>[[23]](http://elinux.org/RPi_Low-level_peripherals#cite_note-23)</sub> the Raspberry Pi Foundation design brings
> out the MIPI CSI-2 (Camera Serial Interface<sub>[[24]](http://elinux.org/RPi_Low-level_peripherals#cite_note-24)</sub>) to a 15-way flat flex
> connector S5, between the Ethernet and HDMI connectors. A compatible
> camera<sub>[[25]](http://elinux.org/RPi_Low-level_peripherals#cite_note-25)</sub> with 5 Megapixels and 1080p video resolution was released
> in May 2013.
>
> ## DSI
>
> On the production board, the Raspberry Pi Foundation design brings out
> the DSI (Display Serial Interface<sub>[[26]](http://elinux.org/RPi_Low-level_peripherals#cite_note-26)</sub>) to a 15-way flat flex connector
> labelled S2, next to Raspberry Pi logo. It has two data lanes and a
> clock lane, to drive a possible future LCD screen device. Some smart
> phone screens use DSI<sub>[[27]](http://elinux.org/RPi_Low-level_peripherals#cite_note-27)</sub>.